# non-unique index on unique constraint column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a table which a unique constraint on a column. This column also has a non-unique clustered index. This column is not the primary key.

are there any issues around this? I can't find any information about this combination.

cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-clustered index is redundant assuming that it really is just on that column and nothing else. A unique constraint is implemented using a unique NCI.